# Generics and MutableLiveData in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, android-livedata

I have two quite similar functions and I'm trying to avoid duplication in my code by the use of generics. The functions have both a try catch block and notify its observers with two MutableLiveData of two different types:

```kotlin
val noWasteRecipesPosts: MutableLiveData<List<Recipe>> = MutableLiveData()
val lastArticlesPosts: MutableLiveData<List<Article>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getNoWasteRecipesPosts() {
        makeCall(service.getRecipes(), noWasteRecipesPosts)
        scope.launch {
            try {
                val response = service.getRecipes().await()
                when (response.isSuccessful) {
                    true -> {
                        response.body()?.let {
                            noWasteRecipesPosts.postValue(ArrayList(response.body()))
                        } ?: run {
                            errorLiveData.postValue(response.message())
                        }
                    }
                    false -> errorLiveData.postValue(response.message())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                noConnectionLiveData.postValue(true)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getLastArticlesPosts(excludeRecipes: Boolean) {
        scope.launch {
            try {
                val response = when (excludeRecipes) {
                    true -> service.getLastArticles(categoriesToExclude = arrayListOf(BlogCategories.NO_WASTE_RECIPES.id))
                        .await()
                    false -> service.getLastArticles()
                        .await()
                }

                when (response.isSuccessful) {
                    true -> {
                        response.body()?.let {
                            lastArticlesPosts.postValue(ArrayList(response.body()))
                        } ?: run {
                            errorLiveData.postValue(response.message())
                        }
                    }
                    false -> errorLiveData.postValue(response.message())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                noConnectionLiveData.postValue(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

To avoid code repeating I'm trying to use generics, but probably in the wrong way. I've defined a function that takes the Deferred api response as first parameter and I would like to pass a MutableLiveData to notify observers as the second parameter:

```kotlin
fun makeCall(function: Deferred<Response<*>>, successLiveData: MutableLiveData<*>) {
        scope.launch {
            try {
                val response = function.await()
                when (response.isSuccessful) {
                    true -> {
                        response.body()?.let {
                            successLiveData.postValue(it) // Compile error here
                        } ?: run {
                            errorLiveData.postValue(response.message())
                        }
                    }
                    false -> errorLiveData.postValue(response.message())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                noConnectionLiveData.postValue(true)
            }
        }

    }
```

Unfortunately I'm missing something and the IDE is giving me a Type mismatch error trying to post the LiveData value:

> Type mismatch: Required : Nothing! Found: Any.

I'm quite confused, do you have any suggestion to make about MutableLiveData and Generics in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `response.body()` type and the `MutableLiveData` type must match. The function signature should be something like this:

```
fun <T> makeCall(function: Deferred<Response<T>>, successLiveData: MutableLiveData<T>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so it would be sufficient to replace the star projection with Any? I think I've already tried that but with no success

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Why `Any`? Put `T` just as in the example and it should work. Notice that `fun <T>` part which defines `T` as the class parameter.

Comment: Understood, now it's clear! I will give it a try on tomorrow, thanks!